# Configure formatting for root logger

Tags: python, logging

I use this code to configure the given logger, or the root logger:

```
def configure_logging(level='INFO', logger=None):
    """Configures a simple console logger with the givel level"""
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    console = logging.StreamHandler()
    console.setFormatter(formatter)
    console.setLevel(level)
    logger = logger or logging.getLogger()  # either the given logger or the root logger
    logger.setLevel(level)
    logger.addHandler(console)
```

Log messages are then duplicated when configuring the root logger. It seems that both the newly configured `console` handler and the default handler are active for the root logger.

How can I disable / remove the default handler of the root logger, and enable exclusively the `console` handler?

Or alternatively, how can I setup formatting of the default handler for the root logger?

Answer (score 4):

This more or less solves my problem:

```
def configure_logging(level='INFO', logger=None):
    """
    Configures a simple console logger with the givel level.
    A usecase is to change the formatting of the default handler of the root logger
    """
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    logger = logger or logging.getLogger()  # either the given logger or the root logger
    logger.setLevel(level)
    # If the logger has handlers, we configure the first one. Otherwise we add a handler and configure it
    if logger.handlers:
        console = logger.handlers[0]  # we assume the first handler is the one we want to configure
    else:
        console = logging.StreamHandler()
        logger.addHandler(console)
    console.setFormatter(formatter)
    console.setLevel(level)
```

Answer (score 0):

The logging module has a default setup 'built in'. If you just want to change the format of the root logger you can use [dictConfig](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig) and continue customizing from there.

Here is a snippet from my logger configuration

```
 cfg = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': _format
        },
    },
    'handlers': {},
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': [],
            'level': level.upper(),
            'propagate': True

        }
    }
}

if console:
    cfg['handlers']['console'] = {
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'level': level.upper(),
        'formatter': 'standard',
    }
    # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
    cfg['loggers']['']['handlers'].append('console')
```

Comment: Good thanks. That is good to fully configure the logging system, less good if I want to reconfigure parts of it.